# python linkedin learning course download

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I got an isssue while executing the script python lld.py to download linkedin course for offline use

C:\Users\Srilokan\Downloads\linkedin>python lld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lld.py", line 13, in 
    reload(sys)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

I have taken this code from https://github.com/mclmza/linkedin-learning-downloader

Please rectify the error

Comment: You may have to open an issue in github repo. Stackoverflow is not the right place for it

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)
 this could be a version issue? Can you check if you are loading 'reload' from the right module ?

If its python 3.3 and above your lld.py file should have something like

```
importlib.reload(module)
```